# How to initialize user-defined MySQL variables in Laravel 4?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Query I want to run needs to initialize a `@total` variable:

```
SET @total = 0;
SELECT ...
    @total := @total + x AS total_x,
    ...
WHERE
    @total < 1000
...
```

Query works when tested via pma, but I fail to run it through Laravel. Tried putting both statements into single `DB::select( $query)` call, and running two consequent calls:

```
DB::statement( DB::raw( 'SET @total := 0'));
$results = DB::select( $query); // only the "select.." part here
```

What's the workaround here?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know anything about laravel, but from the MySQL perspective, instead of two queries like

```
SET @total = 0;
SELECT @total,
...
FROM foo
WHERE...
```

you can do it in one query:

```
SELECT @total,
...
FROM foo,
(SELECT @total := 0) var_init_subquery_alias
WHERE...
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a set of operations within a database you need to use transactions.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#database-transactions